Rust, polars CSV: Is there a way of reading CSV from an `impl BufRead` (or any iterator over bytes)?
I am parsing a bit of a funky, proprietary plain-text file format.
The format contains CSV mixed with non-CSV. I am only interested in the CSV part, which is located somewhere in the file, surrounded by non-csv.
I was wondering if it's possible to give CsvReader/LazyCsvReader something like an std::io::BufReader or even a Vec<u8> that contains the CSV contents, instead of having to provide an AsRef<Path> (which has to point to a file, if I'm not mistaken).
I want to initialize a CSV reader in one of the following ways:

Give it a BufReader that wraps the lines I want to read
Give it a Vec<u8> which contains all the bytes I want to read.

Can this be done, or do I have to write a temporary file, containing only the CSV?
I tried giving CsvReader a BufReader<File>, where I had already advanced the .lines() iterator to where my data starts. But it seams that CsvReader moves the cursor to the start of the stream before reading.

You can pass your Vec<u8> (or any other thing that implemnts AsRef<[u8]>) wrapped in a Cursor to CsvReader::new:
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::io::Cursor;
fn main() {
    let bytes = b"a,b,c\nd,e,f\ng,h,i".to_vec();
    let reader = CsvReader::new(Cursor::new(bytes));
    dbg!(reader.finish().unwrap());
}

If your CSV data is delimited by newlines from your proprietary additional data you can also just use with_skip_rows and with_n_rows to skip leading foreign data and only read the number of rows that are actual CSV:
    let reader = CsvReader::from_path("tmp.data")
        .unwrap()
        .with_skip_rows(1);
        .with_n_rows(Some(2));

tmp.data:
some proprietary none csv data
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
even more proprietary none csv data

Both variants produce the same DataFrame:
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ d   ┆ e   ┆ f   │
│ g   ┆ h   ┆ i   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

Other than that, I don't think you can use a BufReader without implementing MmapBytesReader for a wrapper of it.

Very useful advice, thank you! I understand from this that Cursor<Vec<u8>> and a BufReader<File> must have some traits in common. Could I possibly use a Cursor<T> where T is any iteratble over u8, or won't that work? Specifically, I'm wondering about something like Cursor::new(vec![...].iter().map(|x| ...))

No that won't work, as I've already written, it needs to be a type implementing AsRef<[u8]>. You can see that in the docs on MmapBytesReader which is the trait that CsvReader::new binds it's argument on.
